# EJB Interceptors vs CDI Interceptors

Tags: java, java-ee-6, cdi, ejb-3.1

Is there any difference between EJB Interceptors declared in ejb-jar.xml file vs CDI interceptors declared in beans.xml file?

Both interceptors are declared using annotation @Interceptors. If CDI interceptors apply to EJBs as well then why do EJB interceptors exists?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are right, they are basically the same but the CDI interceptors are little bit more sophisticated - they contain for example Interceptor binding. See [Weld documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/interceptors.html) for reference. Note that there will be probably effort in the future for uniting EJB and CDI (for instance CDI 1.1 allows you to use JTAs declarative transactions which effectively replaces EJB ones) so I expect those two projects to merge in next few years.

Comment: "CDI 1.1 offers declarative transactions" - This is not true. There is no support for this in any version of CDI.

Comment: Actually CDI 1.1 (JSR 347) which is part of Java EE 7 offers declarative transactions using the @javax.transaction.Transactional annotation.

Comment: @MikeArgyriou That's annotation is offered by JTA, not by CDI. It uses CDI, but it is itself not offered by CDI.